# authoring and maintaining multilingual documentation

Tags: localization, multilingual, dita

I need to author and maintain multilingual technical documentation, where each document is made up of some "standard" portions and some specific to the product (industrial equipments): standard portions could be warnings, quotes from laws or regulations, common sentences, or the like.

Each "portion" (i.e. a sentence, a paragraph, an image with its caption, an annotation or a paragraph with an icon) is translated in 13 languages, and each translation should be versioned and completed with references to the author.

Hence each document would result as a "composition" of those portions: a language-specific instance of the document is one using the portions in that specific translation.

Is there any specific technology, standards, or tools for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is [Dita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture) and being it essentially XML-based there is plenty of tools to work with, both standalone XML editors (OxygenXML, XMetal XML, Adobe Framemaker, for full reference: [maintained list of editors](http://www.ditawriter.com/list-of-dita-optimized-editors/)) and extensions to well-known CMS (Drupal, Joomla) and ECM (Alfresco, MS Sharepoint already have; other like Nuxeo can handle by configuring the XML grammar according to the DITA specs).